# How to attach Json Web Tokens to an http header?

Tags: json, node.js, http, token

Most JWT tutorials I've seen say that you can attach it to the headers with AJAX. How do you attach the token on the initial page load?

For example, if a user goes to the base URL '/' and they don't have a token then show them the page. If they do have a token, redirect them to their profile page.

**Edit:**

I'm returning the generated token with a jquery ajax success function then redirecting the user. When the user gets to the home page ('/'), I'd like the access token to be sent via http headers to my server. Then the server can handle the request. However, anytime the user returns (if they close the browser and go to "mywebsite.com" or any other page), I'd like the server to be able to access the token. Are http headers the best way to do this?

```
success: function(token){
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    window.location.href('/');
}
```

If my application was a Single Page App (SPA), I could just use ajax all of the time, but it's not.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't think code would be needed for a question like this, but I'll add it.

Comment: You can use cookies to store it.

Comment: @Prakashsharma Thanks! So is there no way to do this with localStorage as an alternative?

Comment: You need a base index page at / whose only purpose is to server a page with JavaScript that will read local storage then Ajax request with the token in the header to / or another route that will check authentication then on success redirect to the secure area that also again checks the authentication. Or if you want the token to be transmitted automatically then store it as a cookie but you will still need to do checks server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve what you want with HTTP headers. HTTP headers are something which are sent when a request is made to the server. In your case, you want to remember something about the client even if they close their website and come back later. The easiest to do that is through cookies.

Basically generate the JWT token for the client and send it to the client as a cookie. This logic will be written on the server side and there are many libraries available to do this depending on the technology you have chosen for server side. Then everytime the client makes a request to your server, browsers make sure that the stored cookies are sent.